# Difference in outcome of cat command within different locations

Tags: shell

This is my first questionn ever on stackexchange, very excited :)

I'm currently going through OverTheWire War Game and learning the basics of ssh.
I was stuck at bandit5 for I encountered something that I could not understand.

Please refer to [Over The Wire War Game - Bandit Level 5](http://overthewire.org/wargames/bandit/bandit6.html)

Firstly, here are the steps I took to try and solve the problem:

1.See what was available

```
bandit5@bandit:~$ ls
inhere
```

2.Go in to 'inhere'

```
bandit5@bandit:~$ cd inhere
maybehere00  maybehere04  maybehere08  maybehere12  maybehere16
maybehere01  maybehere05  maybehere09  maybehere13  maybehere17
maybehere02  maybehere06  maybehere10  maybehere14  maybehere18
maybehere03  maybehere07  maybehere11  maybehere15  maybehere19
```

3.Since I did not know which folder was correct, I checked the manual of find and managed to add in file size option.

```
bandit5@bandit:~/inhere$ find -size 1033c
./maybehere07/.file2
```

4.Now I knew which file was the correct one, so I accessed it like this...

4a.Go in to the folder where the file belonged (sounds logical right?)

```
bandit5@bandit:~/inhere$ cd maybehere07
```

4b.Cat the file so I can access the answer.

```
bandit5@bandit:~/inhere/maybehere07$ cat ./-file2
```

Now this produced a weird set of long characters...

```
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
```

Which I thought was the password at first, but ofcourse it wasn't :(

So I did a little bit of research and realised all the other players were using the following commands to cat / access the file:
bandit5@bandit:~/inhere$ cat maybehere07/.file2

**So the question is, what is the difference between:**

```
bandit5@bandit:~/inhere/maybehere07$ cat ./-file2
```

and

```
bandit5@bandit:~/inhere$ cat maybehere07/.file2
```

and why has it produced that kind of output?

Thank you all in advance,

Comment: There is no difference... Assuming that you meant `cat maybehere07/file2`

Answer (score 4):

```
cat ./-file2
```

types out the file named `-file2` in the current directory.

```
cat maybehere07/.file2
```

types out the file name `.file2` in the `maybeyere07` subdirectory.

In the first command, your current directory was `maybehere07`; in the second, your current directory was the parent of `maybehere07`. So if you had tried to `cat` the file `.file2` in the first case, you would have gotten the same result as in the second case. But you tried to `cat` a *DIFFERENT* file, one whose name is `-file2`.

BTW, `-file2` seems to be a binary file (image, sound, something else) which is why you get the gibberish you saw.

Answer (score 4):

In step 3 you found a file named `.file2` but in step 4a you access a file named `-file2`. That's not exactly the same name.

Comment: Small correction: those should be `.file2` and `-file2`.

Comment: You're right, corrected it.